# Linking GoDaddy with Elastic BeanStalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I just bought a domain with godaddy [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) (example)

I have then uploaded my flask back end and successfully deployed it to elastic beanstalk.
The elastic beanstalk has given a url as elastic-region.com.
However this url is HTTP, therefore

I have then created a certificate for [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)

Now the problem is I cannot link my godaddy to my elastic bean server.
I have set up the CNAME where Name = www and Value = elastic-region.com.
As well as the certificate as name = xyz value = yzx

After all the configuration I still am not able to connect it to the elastic bean. When I enter the url [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) it redirects be back to godaddy account page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest moving your DNS to route53 DNS service. You can do this by adding a hosted zone in route53 and changing your name servers in GoDaddy. In Route53 you can directly alias towards your elastic beanstalk environment on A / AAAA records.

If you want to continue hosting your DNS at GoDaddy; I would suggest using tools like https://mxtoolbox.com/ to verify if your DNS is set correctly. The method you described in your post would be sufficient to CNAME towards your EB environment.

AWS resource to create an alias towards Elastic beanstalk:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html#routing-to-beanstalk-environment-create-alias-procedure

Some resources to help you change nameservers:

https://www.godaddy.com/help/change-nameservers-for-my-domains-664
https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2020/07/14/migrating-dns-services-aws.aspx

you can also move your whole domain to AWS;

https://blog.shikisoft.com/transferring-domain-registrations-from-godaddy-to-amazon-route-53/

Comment: That worked perfectly, can this be done with amplify as well? I cant seem to get an alias option pointing to amplify

Comment: Not sure. I don't use amplify in my stack. I see you can add domains inside amplify though; 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-amazon-route-53.html